# Trouble increasing width of breadcrumb (ol list) to fill parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to build a simple breadcrumb system on my Bootstrap-powered website.

I have used the red-team-design CSS3 breadcrumbs as inspiration.

This what I have got so far:

[image: screenshot]

What I am trying to do is ensure that the width of the last, active breadcrumb will always fill the parent `ol` element. So the final product should look something like this:

[image: screenshot of wanted result]

I have tried through messing with the margin and padding and a couple of other things but nothing seems to work.

The HTML:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="home.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span> </span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>Travel </span></a></li>
    <li class="current"><a><span>Destination </span></a></li>
</ol>
```

(**NOTE** - I have decided to use a `.current` class instead of the Bootstrap `.active` class)

Here's the CSS:

```
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

.breadcrumb {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}

.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  content:none;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  float:left;
  margin:0 .5em 0 1em;
}

.breadcrumb a {
  background:#ddd;
  padding:.7em 1em;
  float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#444;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  position:relative;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover {
  background:#efc9ab;
}

.breadcrumb a::before, .breadcrumb a::after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:1em;
  background:#ddd;
  transform:skew(-10deg);
}

.breadcrumb a::before {
  left:-.5em;
  border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover::before {
  background:#efc9ab;
}

.breadcrumb a::after {
  right:-.5em;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover::after {
  background:#efc9ab;
}

.breadcrumb .current {
  padding-right:500px;
}

.breadcrumb .current, .breadcrumb .current:hover {
  font-weight:bold;
}

.breadcrumb .current::after, .breadcrumb .current::before {
  content:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (comprehensive [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)). I have

1. set the `ol` to have `display: flex;` to enable flexbox layout;
2. removed the `float` directives from the list items;
3. removed `padding-right` from the `.current` item;
4. made anchors inside items `display: block;` and fill width;
5. made it possible for the `.current` item to grow with `flex-grow: 1; max-width: 100%;`;
6. created a little demo, included below.

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  margin: 0 .5em 0 1em;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.breadcrumb a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: .7em 1em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.breadcrumb a:hover {
  background: #efc9ab;
}

.breadcrumb a::before,
.breadcrumb a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}

.breadcrumb a::before {
  left: -.5em;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover::before {
  background: #efc9ab;
}

.breadcrumb a::after {
  right: -.5em;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover::after {
  background: #efc9ab;
}

.breadcrumb .current,
.breadcrumb .current:hover {
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Destination</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, you Sir are a legend!